# CAD like visualisation of 3D vector data?

Tags: software, visualization

It looks like MATLAB and Mathematica is often used for post-processing and data visualization of 3D vector data.

Now consider you are simulating 3D objects and get out gradient fields etc., is there a software or library one can use to change perspective of this 3D visualized vector data like it usual in CAD tools, so you can zoom away via mouse or into that structure, change perspective without having to alter complete post-processing or doing visualizing of 2D slices to get "3D" impression.

Comment: Maybe MathGL satisfy you?

Comment: If you want to get specific answers, you should tell us the data format of your files.

Comment: @JamesLast: I'm not sure that .omf is descriptive enough to really tell us which format that is. Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 9):

Absolutely. You should check out [VisIt](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/), [Paraview](http://www.paraview.org/), [Tecplot](http://www.tecplot.com/), [Ensight](http://www.ensight.com/), and similar tools.

Answer (score 3):

I would add to that IBM's Data Visualization Explorer, commonly known as [OpenDX](http://www.opendx.org) ([Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_OpenDX)).  It's extremely versatile and open source as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should also take a look at [mayavi](http://mayavi.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @GodricSeer: You see the similar answers(link-only) above. Why me? And i don't agree with you because you can find the  link (if changed) from answers with a little googling.

Comment: I wasn't trying to single you out.  Your answer was flagged as low quality by the system and I saw it in the review menu, where I can only see the question, not other answers.  You answer was passable, but a very obvious point for improvement was to add a sentence or two  about the program you were suggesting and why it met the asker's requirements.